# HTML input 'recommended' property

Tags: html, forms

I'm curious if something like this already exists, either in the Input DOM API or as a well-liked plugin, etc.

The idea is that some input fields can have an attribute of `required` and this informs the browser to respond accordingly, as well as impacts the `validityState` of the DOM object. But what if a field isn't required, but simply "recommended"? For example a form like:

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <div>
    <label for="first_name">Enter your First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" recommended>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="last_name">Enter your Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" required>
  </div>
    <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
  </div>
</form>
```

Last name is required, because we don't want to store any records with an empty last name. First name is not required, but it is *very* unlikely that a person would leave that field blank intentionally. Rather than forcing the user to fill in said field, this property would set some sort of validity state that other code (including CSS and the Validation DOM) could be aware of and handle correctly.

I imagine it would either result in a prompt like "Are you sure you want to leave these fields blank?" and upon clicking 'Yes', this would set some sort of "recommended-check-passed" (or something) property either at the form level or the input level so that on a follow-up submit, it treats the empty field as valid, OR perhaps simply the act of hitting Submit the first time sets a property like "recommended-prompt-occurred", such that the only expectation is that the form reflect these empty fields (probably changing their color) and that a follow up Submit would go through (so no need for the user to explicitly say "Yes I meant to leave those blank").

I think most of the above could be accomplished with simple data- attributes, but it starts to get convoluted when I think about the validity State and all that.

Sorry if this question is "too broad", but I couldn't find anything online and was hoping to avoid reinventing the wheel. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed no "Recommended" attribute. As you've stated before, to accomplish this has be through a script. However, there is the ":optional" CSS selector ([source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_optional.asp)), which can only be applied to input elements if they don't have the "Required" attribute.

#### Opinion

I think a "recommended" attribute always has to tag along with additional logic to maybe fill the alert a user gets when leaving those fields empty. So only using an attribute won't suffice. Therefor, creating such an attribute is redundant, because you could easily include those validation scripts in the form submit validation.

Answer (score 1):

Well your question got me thinking. So I started to play around. Maybe you could get away with something like this.

It shows recommend tooltip on hover an also if required element is left empty it reminds user of recommended filed with tooltip and also gets yellow border effect same in contrast with required element. Border is also activated on activated on focus().

First I tried using some sort of CSS tool-tip but problem was activating it, I couldn't assign hover, active or focus on wanted tool tip because required HTML input field element was always stilling the show what ever I tried. Maybe someone else can do it in that direction.

So I resorted to [jquery-ui tooltip()](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) and HTML `title=""` property. There is also HTML `data-tooltip` property but I couldn't active it.

Function also looks if `recommended` filed is empty or not and activates the tool-tip accordingly.

This post addresses only a bit of functionality mentioned in OP'S post, and I had a bit of fun thinking about it so I'm gonna share this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var emptyornot = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
  //console.log(emptyornot);
  if ($.isEmptyObject(emptyornot)) {
  $("#first_name").addClass("recommended");
  $( "#tooltip" ).tooltip({
  open: function( event, ui ) {}
  });
$( "#tooltip" ).tooltip("open");
  }else {  
  $("#first_name").removeClass("recommended");
  } 
}
$("#first_name").focus();
```

```css
#first_name:focus{
  border-color: #FFFF00;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px           rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
} 
.recommended{
  border-color: #FFFF00;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px           rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<form action="" method="get">
  <div>
    <label for="first_name">Enter your First Name: </label>
    <div id="tooltip" title="RECOMENDED">  
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"
    class="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>
  <div>
    <label for="last_name">Enter your Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" required>
  </div>
    <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" onclick="myFunction()">
  </div>
</form>
```